# loop in GUI, displaying n times

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, text, double

In the following code within the button method, when 'work hours' are more than 40, the program need to display “Bonus!” three time on the Form.

my question is ... instead of simple if statement, how do we use loop (for loop/ while loop the easiest way) in this form here?

I'm just wondering what is the simplest form of loop when it comes to displaying a message more than one time.

Thanks a lot,
Alex Del

```cs
double hrsWorked;
double payRate, Salary;
hrsWorked = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
payRate = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
Salary = hrsWorked * payRate;

//need to use a loop (either for loop or while loop saying if no. hours is more than 40 (41, 42, 43, ...) 
//shows 'Bonus' three times and when recalculate for any keyed in input again shows 3 times 'Bonus' before its Calculation as shown in the expected output image.





//if (hrsWorked > 40)
//{
//    label3.Text = "Bonus";
//    label4.Text = "Bonus";
//    label5.Text = "Bonus";
//}

label6.Text = "calculated amount is " + Salary;
```

[image]

Comment: So do you want it three times or four times? Decide.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Please provide a good [mcve], explain _precisely_ what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out. The loop in the code you posted is ridiculous, because it will run for approximately 2 billion iterations (i.e. until the `num1` variable overflows and winds up negative). Not to mention that you appear to be modifying the actual hours worked variable in the loop. Please improve this question. Read [ask] for information on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and comment, yes I need to improve the code, and question, and the for loop I used in the code was not the answer, was just an idea of showing that I need to use for loop somehow, need to improve the way I asked this question, thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper and Peter once again for your comments and feedbacks.
I've edited and improved the question:
further clarification to the question I've asked which I've commented in the code as well is:

need to use a loop (either for loop or while loop saying if no. hours is more than 40 (41, 42, 43, ...) 
shows  and display word 'Bonus' three times and when recalculate for any keyed in input again shows 3 times 'Bonus' before its Calculation as shown in the expected output image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count DOWN to 40 from your current # of work hours, and use a multiline text box or a label with wrapping:

```
StringBuilder sbResults = new StringBuilder();
for(double i = num1; i  > 40; i--)
{
   // Each loop iteration here is one hour over 40 hours
   sbResults.AppendLine("Bonus!");
}
YourMultilineControl.Text = sbResults.ToString();
```

If you want just one line for every 10 hours over, then change i-- to i -= 10.

On a side note, you should really get into the habit of immediately giving things good names. Don't post questions here with "num1” and "TextBox1" and "label3" names - it's impossible to know for sure what those are referring to when looking at the code. Instead, use "numWorkHours" and "txtWorkHours" and so on.

Oh and one last note - a loop probably isn't the most efficient way of doing this. Subtract total hours - 40 to find the number of hours over 40 and then use that number to repeat a string as many times as necessary.

Comment: Did you change "YourMultilineControl" to an instance of an actual multiline textbox or label?

Comment: Good catch on the type. Edited. I agree it isn't perfectly clear - I was basing it off of the OP's initial attempt at the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and feedback comments.

Comment: Is there any way to use either for loop/while loop saying if the hours worked is more than 40 hrs, rather than using that IF Statement which I used in the code above, we use loop in this GUI form window?

Comment: As I have tried this code and if I keep using any other value above 40 (i,e, 41, 53, 76 for example), it keeps the word 'Bonus' and it added more Bonus to the form, I mean it doeas not restart to 3 times display.

Comment: So when do you want it to show only 1 time? When do you only want it 3 times?

Comment: 3 times 'Bonus' in 3 line display is expected once user entered value of no. of worked hours anytime which is more than 40 hrs, otherwise, just the normal output message using 
label6.Text = "calculated amount is " + Salary; which displays total calculated amount.  

Need to use a loop (either for loop or while loop saying if no. hours is more than 40 (41, 42, 43, ...) shows and display word 'Bonus' three times and when recalculate for any keyed in input again shows 3 times 'Bonus' before its Calculation as shown in the expected output image

Comment: In that case, I don't understand why you would want a loop for this if it's a simple true/false situation. You would use a loop when you want something to occur multiple times where the condition might change. In this case, you are checking the condition ONCE and you're setting values ONCE, so the proper way to do this is with an if() statement. Can you help explain why you want to use a loop?